# Generating query strings in Laravel 4

Tags: string, url, laravel, laravel-4

I have a named route

```
Route::get('login/facebook', array(
      'as'   > 'login.facebook.authorise', 
      'uses' => 'AuthController@getFBAuthorise'
));
```

and want to produce a URL pointing to it with a query string appended.

For example:

`URL::route('login.facebook.authorise', array("next"=>'/dashboard/')`

would produce

`/login/facebook?next=/dashboard/`

Is something like this built in to the framework? If not, what is the best way to try and do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL helper can do this.

http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls

`echo link_to_route('route.name', $title, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array());`

EDIT: To get only the URL :

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

`$url = URL::route('route.name', $parameters);`

Comment: That generates an HTML link with tags - not a raw URL

Comment: Sorry. `URL::route()` will do what you want.

Comment: Neither link_to_route() nor URL::route() will create a URL with a query string added to it.  Laravel route and URL functions just aren't made to work with query strings.  For that, just use PHP's http_build_query().

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the party

Just dove into the classes and methods for building urls and you can do this:

```
link_to_route('login.facebook.authorise','Facebook Login',array('next'=>'/Dashboard/'))
```

So. the array will always fallback to query params unless the names are declared in the route.

Answer (score 0):

If the use case for this is redirecting to a page after logging in  then you could use

```
Redirect::intended('dashboard');
```

As seen here http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

Sorry if that's not what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I knew about the intended routing but this is to be used across other parts of the site also. I also want a quick way to generate urls with tracking information.

In emails I send out, I want to build complex query strings. Is there a built in way to do this?